# How to Install and configure Redis on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I install and configure Redis on AWS ElasticBeanstalk? Does anyone know how to write an .ebextension script to accomplish that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk does provide [resource configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) via the .ebextensions folder. Essentially you need to tell Elastic Beanstalk what you would like provisioned in addition to your application. For provisioning into a default vpc. You need to

create an .ebextensions folder

add an elasticache.config file

and include the following contents.

```
Resources:
  MyCacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Lock cache down to webserver access only"
      SecurityGroupIngress :
        - IpProtocol : "tcp"
          FromPort :
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName : "CachePort"
              DefaultValue: "6379"
          ToPort :
            Fn::GetOptionSetting:
              OptionName : "CachePort"
              DefaultValue: "6379"
          SourceSecurityGroupName:
            Ref: "AWSEBSecurityGroup"
  MyElastiCache:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster"
    Properties:
      CacheNodeType:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "CacheNodeType"
          DefaultValue : "cache.t1.micro"
      NumCacheNodes:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "NumCacheNodes"
          DefaultValue : "1"
      Engine:
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName : "Engine"
          DefaultValue : "redis"
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        -
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - MyCacheSecurityGroup
            - GroupId

Outputs:
  ElastiCache:
    Description : "ID of ElastiCache Cache Cluster with Redis Engine"
    Value :
      Ref : "MyElastiCache"
```

Referenced from: "How to add ElasticCache resources to Elastic Beanstalk VPC"
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-elasticache.html

Comment: I did this and get the
`[Error: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED]`. Probably command redis-server hasn't started. Any way to check Redis Status?

Comment: @theChinmay redis will be deployed standalone, your app is supposed to get the IP from an environment variable and connect to that IP rather than to localhost

Comment: @LucaG. you know how can I get the IP or host in Amazon Elasticbeanstalk NodeJS app? Thanks

Comment: @TezroSolutions with the example provided by @TerryB, it should be  something like this:

`option_settings:`
    `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:`
       `REDIS_CLUSTER: '\`{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyElastiCache", "RedisEndpoint.Address"]}\`'`

For reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#d0e52037

Comment: Will work only in single docker environment. Doesn't work in multi docker environment

Answer (score 37):

The accepted answer is great if you are using ElastiCache (like RDS, but for Memcached or Redis). But, if what you are trying to do is tell EB to provision Redis into the EC2 instance in which it spins up your app, you want a different config file, something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yustam/9086610#file-redis-config):

```
packages: 
  yum:
    gcc-c++: [] 
    make: []
sources:
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.4.tar.gz
commands:
  redis_build:
    command: make
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_001:
    command: sed -i -e "s/daemonize no/daemonize yes/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_002:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory <bytes>/maxmemory 500MB/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_config_003:
    command: sed -i -e "s/# maxmemory-policy volatile-lru/maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru/" redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
  redis_server:
    command: src/redis-server redis.conf
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/redis-2.8.4
```

**IMPORTANT:** The commands are executed in alphabetical order by name, so if you pick different names than `redis_build`, `redis_config_xxx`, `redis_server`, make sure they are such that they execute in the way you expect.

Your other option is to containerize your app with Redis using Docker, then deploy your app as some number of Docker containers, instead of whatever language you wrote it in. Doing that for a Flask app is described [here](http://blog.trauzti.com/elasticbeanstalk-flask-redis-hyperloglog.html).

You can jam it all into one container and deploy that way, which is easier, but doesn't scale well, or you can use AWS' Elastic Beanstalk multi-container deployments. If you have used `docker-compose`, you can use [this](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) tool to turn a `docker-compose.yml` into the form AWS wants, `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

Comment: Do we need to create a new ElastiCache cluster for Redis on AWS? Or we can simply add above script in the file and it's done?

Comment: kpp, if you're using elastic beanstalk, this will install redis on the VM it provisions. This may be what you want. ElastiCache is for when you outgrow this

Comment: This sollution assumes you only have a single server, right? To run as expected (a single logical Redis), the install would have to be configured to run clustered (Sentinel?). I'm not familiar enough with that to say how to accomplish that though.

Comment: That's a good point, Martin, and given the traffic this answer gets, I should update it. But I haven't worked with Beanstalk since shortly after this was written, so I am not certain how to do this. If anyone has a suggestion, I will update my answer.