# Setting up ElastiCache Redis with Elastic BeanStalk + Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

Another stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528395/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-elasticbeanstalk) says you need to set up a elasticache.config file to create Redis servers with ElastiCache automatically.

However, can I just create a Redis instance on AWS (Elasticache) and add its endpoint into Django settings? Eg, with [Django-redis](http://niwinz.github.io/django-redis/latest/#_installation):

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://<REDIS AWS ENDPOINT AND PORT HERE>",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the above could cause trouble with multiple beanstalk server instances. Given this, I am tempted to use MemCache and not Redis, given that there is a Django package written explicitly for interfacing with AWS Elasticache for Memcache: [django-elasticache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-elasticache).

Thanks, 
Andy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: I have not used Elastic Beanstalk, however I can confirm that if you create a Redis *instance* (that is: cluster mode disabled) in ElastiCache it will work fine with `django-redis`. Just insert the `primary_endpoint` into the Django config you posted.

N.B. If you plan to use read replicas, set it up like this:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": [
            "redis://<MASTER ENDPOINT>",
            "redis://<SLAVE ENDPOINT>",
        ]
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

If you spin up a Redis *cluster* however, you cannot use vanilla `django-redis`. You'll have to use use [`redis-py-cluster`](https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster) with it as described [in this post](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/issues/208#issuecomment-352585533). Replicated here:

```
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
    'LOCATION': 'redis://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.cache.amazonaws.com/0',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'REDIS_CLIENT_CLASS': 'rediscluster.RedisCluster',
      'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'rediscluster.connection.ClusterConnectionPool',
      'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {
        'skip_full_coverage_check': True # AWS ElasticCache has disabled CONFIG commands
      }
    }
  }
}
```